# How can I plot graphs inside columns in streamlit

Tags: python, altair, streamlit

I have tried the following method-

```
col1, col2, col3 = st.beta_columns(3)
col1.header = "confirmed"
col1.write("col1")
fig_con = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
  alt.X("days"),
  alt.Y("confirmed")
)
col1.st.altair_chart(fig_con)

col2.header = "recovered"
col2.write("col2")
fig_rec = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
  alt.X("days"),
  alt.Y("recovered")
)
col2.st.altair_chart(fig_rec)

col3.header = "deceased"
col3.write("col3")
fig_dec = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
  alt.X("days"),
  alt.Y("deceased")
)
col3.st.altair_chart(fig_dec)
```

But this seems to be the wrong syntax.

And if I do this-

```
col1, col2, col3 = st.beta_columns(3)
col1.header = "confirmed"
col1.write("col1")
fig_con = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
  alt.X("days"),
  alt.Y("confirmed")
)
st.altair_chart(fig_con)

col2.header = "recovered"
col2.write("col2")
fig_rec = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
  alt.X("days"),
  alt.Y("recovered")
)
st.altair_chart(fig_rec)

col3.header = "deceased"
col3.write("col3")
fig_dec = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
  alt.X("days"),
  alt.Y("deceased")
)
st.altair_chart(fig_dec)
```

This plots them one below the other.

The documentation is a bit scarce on this as the columns feature is in beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `with col:`

```py
with col1:    
    col1.header = "confirmed"
    col1.write("col1")
    fig_con = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
      alt.X("days"),
      alt.Y("confirmed")
    )
    st.altair_chart(fig_con)
    
with col2:
    col2.header = "recovered"
    col2.write("col2")
    fig_rec = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
      alt.X("days"),
      alt.Y("recovered")
    )
    st.altair_chart(fig_rec)

with col3:
    col3.header = "deceased"
    col3.write("col3")
    fig_dec = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
      alt.X("days"),
      alt.Y("deceased")
    )
    st.altair_chart(fig_dec)
```